# Autoplay Swiper slider on hover and pause it when moving the mouse outside of it

Tags: javascript, slider, swiper.js

I'm using the following options in an autoplaying Swiper slider to pause it on hover:

```
autoplay: {
    delay: 3000,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
    pauseOnMouseEnter: true,
}
```

My question is, is there a way to do the opposite? Start autoplaying the slider when hovering over it and pause it when moving the mouse outside of it?

Comment: You will probably had to add `mouseEnter` and `mouseLeave` event handlers to the swiper container which would call `swiper.resume()` and `swiper.pause()` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

expanding on the comment by @Maksym Shcherban, you can call `swiper.autoplay.stop()` immediately after the initialization and call `swiper.autoplay.start()` on `mouseover` event and `swiper.autoplay.stop()` on `mouseout` event

here's a preview:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.css"
    />
    <title>Parcel1 Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- Slider main container -->
    <div id="swiper" class="swiper">
      <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        ...
      </div>
      <!-- If we need pagination -->
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

      <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

      <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
      <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.ts"></script>

    <script type="module">
      import Swiper from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.mjs";

      const swiper = new Swiper(".swiper", {
        // Optional parameters
        direction: "vertical",
        loop: true,

        autoplay: {
          delay: "3000",
        },

        // If we need pagination
        pagination: {
          el: ".swiper-pagination",
        },

        // Navigation arrows
        navigation: {
          nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
          prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
        },

        // And if we need scrollbar
        scrollbar: {
          el: ".swiper-scrollbar",
        },
      });
      swiper.autoplay.stop();
      const swiperContainer = document.getElementById("swiper");
      swiperContainer.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
        swiper.autoplay.start();
      });
      swiperContainer.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
        swiper.autoplay.stop();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

also here's a [link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/swiper-reverse-autoplay-tykdpq?file=%2Findex.html%3A66%2C26&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq46dfin00062e66dzjtnaby%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq46dfim00022e66stlke9b2%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq46dfim00032e66di0vmjt6%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq46dfim00052e6641u7bzj8%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B40%252C60%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clq46dfim00022e66stlke9b2%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq46dfim00022e66stlke9b2%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq478tsz00022e66pb6zl2vp%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A66%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A26%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A66%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A26%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Findex.html%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq478tsz00022e66pb6zl2vp%2522%257D%252C%2522clq46dfim00052e6641u7bzj8%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq46dfim00042e66usg7sb9n%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq46dfim00052e6641u7bzj8%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq46dfim00042e66usg7sb9n%2522%257D%252C%2522clq46dfim00032e66di0vmjt6%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq46dfim00032e66di0vmjt6%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A0%257D) to code sandbox where i've tested it works